# Cosinus of an array in Python

Tags: python, arrays

I want to obtain results of cosine for each value.

```
import numpy as np

import math

t = np.arange(0, 20.5, 0.5)

print(math.cos(t))
```

I get 'TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars' error.

Comment: it is `np.cos(t)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to apply the operation to every element of the array rather than to the entire array.

## Solution with math

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import math
>>> t = np.arange(0, 20.5, 0.5)
>>> print([math.cos(element) for element in t])

[1.0, 0.8775825618903728, 0.5403023058681398, 0.0707372016677029, -0.4161468365471424, -0.8011436155469337, -0.9899924966004454, -0.9364566872907963, -0.6536436208636119, -0.2107957994307797, 0.28366218546322625, 0.70866977429126, 0.960170286650366, 0.9765876257280235, 0.7539022543433046, 0.3466353178350258, -0.14550003380861354, -0.6020119026848236, -0.9111302618846769, -0.9971721561963784, -0.8390715290764524, -0.4755369279959925, 0.004425697988050785, 0.4833047587530059, 0.8438539587324921, 0.9977982791785807, 0.9074467814501962, 0.594920663309892, 0.1367372182078336, -0.354924266788705, -0.7596879128588213, -0.9784534628188842, -0.9576594803233847, -0.7023970575027135, -0.27516333805159693, 0.2194399632114593, 0.6603167082440802, 0.939524893748256, 0.9887046181866692, 0.7958149698139441, 0.40808206181339196]
```

## Solution with numpy

However the better solution is to use `np.cos` which also accepts an array:

```
>>> np.cos(t)
array([ 1.        ,  0.87758256,  0.54030231,  0.0707372 , -0.41614684,
       -0.80114362, -0.9899925 , -0.93645669, -0.65364362, -0.2107958 ,
        0.28366219,  0.70866977,  0.96017029,  0.97658763,  0.75390225,
        0.34663532, -0.14550003, -0.6020119 , -0.91113026, -0.99717216,
       -0.83907153, -0.47553693,  0.0044257 ,  0.48330476,  0.84385396,
        0.99779828,  0.90744678,  0.59492066,  0.13673722, -0.35492427,
       -0.75968791, -0.97845346, -0.95765948, -0.70239706, -0.27516334,
        0.21943996,  0.66031671,  0.93952489,  0.98870462,  0.79581497,
        0.40808206])
```

## Speed comparison

The second solution has huge benefits in terms of speed:

```
In [9]: %timeit [math.cos(element) for element in t]
The slowest run took 5.19 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.54 µs per loop

In [10]: %timeit np.cos(t)
The slowest run took 21.73 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.1 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use something that allows arrays (faster!), or use a list comprehension.

- `np.cos(t)`: *1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.81 µs per loop*
- `[math.cos(x) for x in t]`: *100000 loops, best of 3: 11.2 µs per loop*

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `np.cos` :

```
t = np.arange(0, 20.5, 0.5)
print np.cos(t) # which accepts np.arrays
```

Or you can use `math.cos` :

```
t = np.arange(0, 20.5, 0.5)
print([math.cos(element) for element in t])
```